# Excel getting totals for categories across worksheets

Tags: excel

So I have column A (cat) and column B (Amt) on lots of separate works sheets.

```
Cat | Amt

1   | 3.4
4   | 7.4
2   | 8.4
4   | 9.4
```

What I need is to have a grand total for each category type across all the worksheets.

So a total for category 4, a total for category 2 etc.

Comment: How many is "lots of separate works sheets"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more suitable for VBA solution, however if you know how many unique "Cat" you have, then it can be done without VBA.

1. For each sheet on C column add SUMIF formula, this will give sum for each group.
   `C2=SUMIF($A:$A,A2,$B:$B)` - copy it down for each row.
2. On Sheet11 Column A is your unique "Cat" list. Columns B1 to K1, name them as Sheet1, Sheet2, ...Sheet10.
   `B2=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,INDIRECT(B$1&"!$A:$C"),3,FALSE),0)` - copy it for each row, column.
3. Column L will be GrandTotal.
   `G2=SUM(B2:K2)` - copy it for each row.

Comment: So I add SUMIF($A:$A,A2,$B:$B) on every row without changing any of the variables?

Comment: Yes, just copy down the formula.